# Storyboard UILabel align image

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm working with storyboards, and I want to automatically make a `UILabel` align with an image (via constraints). For example, I have:

[image: My storyboard]

And as a result, I want to see something like this with one `UILabel`:

[image: Desired result]

I haven't found any info on how to do this. Is it possible to do this? Do I need to use custom libraries or can I do this via constraints?

Comment: unfortunately constraints aren't going to help with this kind of problem and i dont know of any elegant way of solving this, but maybe using an `NSAttachment` in a `NSAttributedString` might be a step in the right direction...

Comment: I hate to say it, because it sounds so inelegant and non-native, but perhaps you should consider using a web view?

Comment: It can be done using native controls. Check out TextKit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html A nice tutorial -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial which also teaches how to solve this specific problem using exclusion paths.